# Merge text file with a csv database file using pandas

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, pandas

[Update my question]

I have a text file looks like below,

```
#File_infoomation1
#File_information2
A B C D
1 2 3 4.2 
5 6 7 8.5   #example.txt separate by tab '\t' column A dtype is object
```

I'd like to merge the text file with a csv database file based on column E. The column contains integer.

```
E,name,age
1,john,23
5,mary,24  # database.csv  column E type is int64
```

So I tried to read the text file then remove first 2 unneeded head lines.

```
    example = pd.read_csv('example.txt', header = 2, sep = '\t')
    database = pd.read_csv('database.csv') 
    request = example.rename(columns={'A': 'E'})
    New_data = request.merge(database, on='E', how='left')
```

But the result does not appear the stuff I want, while it shows NaN in column name and age,

I think `int64` and `object` dtype is where the mistake, dose anyone know how to work this out?

```
E,B,C,D,name,age
1,2,3,4.2,NaN,NaN
5,6,7,8.5,NaN,NaN
```

Comment: Do you want to query like `example.A == database.E` then select row?

Comment: yes, change to the same column name then using merge to combine two files.

Comment: In your example.txt file the values are not tab separated like `\t`. they are separated with `\s`

Comment: Everything works fine, the problem is in your reading of files. Could you post your `request` and `database` with `print(request)`? If you unsure about how many spaces do you have you could use separator as `regex` like: `df = pd.read_csv(file, sep='\s+')`

Answer (score 0):

You just need to edit this in your code:

instead of

```
  example = pd.read_csv('example.txt', header = 2, sep = '\t', delim_whitespace=False )
```

Use this:

```
 example = pd.read_csv('example.txt',  sep = ' ' ,index_col= False)
```

Comment: My example.txt file is separated by tab '\t', sorry I did not say this clearly. I revised my question. Thanks,

Comment: You don't need to specify `index_col=False` because it's default value: `index_col=None` which is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I tried reading your files with:

```
example = pd.read_csv('example.txt', header = 2, sep = '\t')

# Renaming
example.columns = ['E','B','C','D']

database = pd.read_csv('database.csv')

New_data = example.merge(database, on='E', how='left')
```

And this returns:

```
   E  B  C    D  name  age
0  1  2  3  4.2  john   23
1  5  6  7  8.5  mary   24
```

EDIT: actually is not clear the separator of the original `example.txt` file. If it is space try putting `sep='\s'` instead `sep=' '` for space.

Comment: Sorry it still does not work, still shows NaN, I think it is probably caused by my data type. I even transfer the example.txt to csv file first. It still does not success.

Comment: I'm sorry, I've just copied and pasted your dataframes (in the first one I manually add tabs as you said). Maybe there's still something wrong with the formatting? Try parsing the .txt file with different separators.

Comment: I try `print database.dtypes()`, it prints out **'Series' object is not callable**, then I try `print example.dtypes()`, it shows **object** in the first column A. Do you know how to deal with this problem?

Comment: `\s` stands for space in Regex. Here you have to use `sep = ' '`

Comment: You could use both sep='  ', and sep='\s' for the single space.